# BigDecimal JavaScript Library Error - 'wrap_meth.inner_method' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, bigdecimal

I am using the BigDecimal library for JavaScript.

https://github.com/iriscouch/bigdecimal.js

```
var val1 = new BigDecimal(document.getElementById('id1').value);

var val2 = new BigDecimal(document.getElementById('id2').value);

var val3 = val1.add(val2);
```

The add method is working in Firefox but giving the following error on IE8.

> Message: 'wrap_meth.inner_method' is null or not an object
>   Line: 582
>   Char: 9
>   Code: 0
>   URI: http://localhost:8080/AppName/js/bigdecimal.js

It's giving me the same error for other big decimal methods like compareTo and setScale.

How do I get around the error?

Comment: Hi, I am the author or that library. I believe this might be a bug with the build system. The build was specifically targeted for WebKit or Safari if I recall, so it might require an independent build for IE. Would you please file a bug in the issue tracker at GitHub and I will produce an IE build for testing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been brought up on github. https://github.com/iriscouch/bigdecimal.js/issues/2

Pasted here for convenience:

I also saw this issue. I was able to resolve it by updating the following line in bigdecimal.js:

```
return wrap_meth.inner_method.apply(this, [args]);
```

To:

```
var m = wrap_meth.inner_method ? wrap_meth.inner_method : arguments.callee.inner_method;
return m.apply(this, [args]);
```